# Need suggestions on javascript word to image matching project

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, css-animations

Newbie to JAVASCRIPT here. I'm trying to create a practice project that has buttons on one side and images on another side. when the button clicked, It will be possible to draw a line between the button and images. In case of a match, the line turns green. In case of mismatch, the line turns red. So far, I've tried,
Here's the code :

```js
// word inputs
const tomatoWord = document.getElementById('inputA');
const iceCreamWord = document.getElementById('inputB');
const chickenWord = document.getElementById('inputC');
const lionWord = document.getElementById('inputD');
const carWord = document.getElementById('inputE');

// image inputs
const lionImg = document.getElementById('inputF');
const tomatoImg = document.getElementById('inputG');
const carImg = document.getElementById('inputH');
const iceCreamImg = document.getElementById('inputI');
const chickenImg = document.getElementById('inputJ');

// svg path
const svgPath = document.getElementById('svgPath');


// answer arrays
const testArr2 = ['classAtoImage', 'classBtoWord'];

var testArr = [];

// adding event function
function addEvents(input, cName) {
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked && !(input.classList.contains(cName))) {
      testArr.push(cName);
      console.log(testArr);
      matchInArray(testArr, testArr2);
    } else {
      testArr = testArr.filter(e => e !== cName);
      console.log(testArr);
    }
  })
}

// matching array
const matchInArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  if (JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2)) {
    console.log(' matches');
    addLine();
  } else {
    removeLine();
    console.log(' not matching');
  }
}

// adding events to words
addEvents(tomatoWord, 'classAtoImage');
addEvents(iceCreamWord, 'classBtoImage');
addEvents(chickenWord, 'classCtoImage');
addEvents(lionWord, 'classDtoImage');
addEvents(carWord, 'classEtoImage');

// adding events to images
addEvents(lionImg, 'classAtoWord');
addEvents(tomatoImg, 'classBtoWord');
addEvents(carImg, 'classEtoWord');
addEvents(iceCreamImg, 'classDtoWord');
addEvents(chickenImg, 'classCtoWord');

// test function
const testDiv = document.getElementById('myDIV');

function addLine() {
  testDiv.classList.add('transform-active');
}

function removeLine() {
  testDiv.classList.remove('transform-active');
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus,
label {
  outline: none;
}

img,
label,
input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-container {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  padding: 0 50px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  display: flex;
}

.form,
.images {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.svg-path {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.form {
  width: 100%;
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
} */

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}

#labelA {
  background-color: #9cba58;
  border: 2px solid #718a39;
}

#labelB {
  background-color: #c0504e;
  border: 2px solid #833c3a;
}

#labelC {
  background-color: #fc9644;
  border: 2px solid #af6d39;
}

#labelD {
  background-color: #8165a2;
  border: 2px solid #574d66;
}

#labelE {
  background-color: #4aacc5;
  border: 2px solid #48777f;
}

.form>aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

img {
  width: 63.33%;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-self: center;
}

.car-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.ice-cream-img {
  width: 44%;
}

.img-input-2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
}

.img-input-3,
.img-input-4,
.img-input-5 {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}


/* hidding default checkbox */

input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

input[type="checkbox"]+span:before {
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a green background */

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:before {
  background: green;
  content: "";
}

#inputA:checked+span::before {
  background: green;
  content: "";
}


/* #inputF:checked ~ span::before {
  background: red;
  content: "";
} */


/* special span class for color change */


/* input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span.special:before {
  background: red;
  content: " ";
} */


/* selecting first five checkbox's */

.input-1,
.input-2,
.input-3,
.input-4,
.input-5 {
  top: -1px !important;
}


/* selecting last five checkbox's */

.input-6
/* .input-7,
.input-8,
.input-9,
.input-10 */

{
  top: -33px !important;
}

.input-7 {
  top: -30px !important;
}

.input-8 {
  top: -28px !important;
}

.input-9 {
  top: -31px !important;
}

.input-10 {
  top: -19px !important;
}


/* checkmark classes */

.checkmark-6,
.checkmark-7,
.checkmark-8,
.checkmark-9,
.checkmark-10 {
  position: relative;
}

.checkmark-6 {
  top: 22px;
}

.checkmark-7 {
  top: 26px;
}

.checkmark-8 {
  top: 30px;
}

.checkmark-9 {
  top: 33px;
}

.checkmark-10 {
  top: 29px;
}


/* testing line css */

.outer-div {
  position: fixed;
  left: 545px;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 75px;
  display: flex;
}

.line {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 10px;
  width: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.transform {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.transform-active {
  background-color: #45cee0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 275px;
  transform: rotate(22deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: -10px;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#svgPath {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-container">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="checkbox-1">
      <aside class="input-aside">
        <label for="inputA" id="labelA">tomato</label>
        <input class="input-1" type="checkbox" name="" id="inputA">
        <span class=" checkmark-1" id="lionImg"></span>
        <div class="outer-div">
          <div class="line transform" id="myDIV"></div>
        </div>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-2 classBtoimage">
      <aside class="input-aside">
        <label for="inputB" id="labelB">ice cream</label>
        <input class="input-2" type="checkbox" name="" id="inputB">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-3 classCtoimage">
      <aside class="input-aside">
        <label for="inputC" id="labelC">chicken</label>
        <input class="input-3" type="checkbox" name="" id="inputC">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-4 classDtoimage">
      <aside class="input-aside">
        <label for="inputD" id="labelD">lion</label>
        <input class="input-4" type="checkbox" name="" id="inputD">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-5 classEtoimage">
      <aside class="input-aside">
        <label for="inputE" id="labelE">car</label>
        <input class="input-5" type="checkbox" name="" id="inputE">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- LEFT SIDE WORD SECTION end -->

  <!-- CENTER SVG PATH start -->
  <div id="svgPath">

  </div>
  <!-- CENTER SVG PATH start -->

  <!-- RIGHT SIDE IMAGE SECTION start -->
  <form class="images">
    <div class="checkbox-6 classAtoword">
      <aside class="input-aside">
        <input class="input-6" type="checkbox" name="" id="inputF">
        <span class="checkmark-6 "></span>
        <label for="inputF" id="labelF">
                        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/140693/isolated/preview/4ab92e6350ef4e1b84e9a98c8472545c-lion-cartoon-by-vexels.png" alt="">
                    </label>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-7 classBtoword">
      <aside class="input-aside">
        <input class="input-7" type="checkbox" name="" id="inputG">
        <span class="checkmark-7"></span>
        <label for="inputG" id="labelG">
                        <img src="https://freesvg.org/img/mini-tomato.png" alt="">
                    </label>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-8 classCtoword">
      <aside class="input-aside">
        <input class="input-8" type="checkbox" name="" id="inputH">
        <span class="checkmark-8"></span>
        <label for="inputH" id="labelH">
                        <img class="car-img" src="https://freesvg.org/img/DTRave_Cartoon_Car.png" alt="">
                    </label>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-9 classDtoword">
      <aside class="input-aside">
        <input class="input-9" type="checkbox" name="" id="inputI">
        <span class="checkmark-9"></span>
        <label for="inputI" id="labelI">
                        <img class="ice-cream-img" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/1tLzmSUeoJ49nya04dewnM8X7QVP5kQvGY4vwi3kGtjSVubK4-EAL4hVBEe9Vpv0XPBYDmY0qtVDGaPe5B2DHLGJ3vM4ct0" alt="">
                    </label>
      </aside>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox-10 classEtoword">
      <aside class="input-aside">
        <input class="input-10" type="checkbox" name="" id="inputJ">
        <span class="checkmark-10"></span>
        <label for="inputJ" id="labelJ">
                        <img src="https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/chicken_cartoon_clip_art_7108.jpg" alt="">
                    </label>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!-- RIGHT SIDE IMAGE SECTION end -->
</main>
```

I need suggestions on the logic of this project. Just need some ideas on how could it be possible to make this project.
[image]

Comment: You should always create a [mcve] **in the question itself** (as I just did)

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks for the suggestions, friend. won't do these mistakes again